# React tensorflow: Set back camera with getUserMedia

Tags: tensorflow, getusermedia

I'm using tensorflow - react for object recognition on chrome.
I want to use the back camera instead of the front one.

Here is the code:

```
  const webcamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: false,
        })
```

It seems that adding  `facingMode: 'environment'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you added `facingMode: 'environment'`? It should work with

```js
navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: {facingMode: 'environment'},
          audio: false,
        })
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you very much. My mistake was that i left true.

Comment: can you accept the answer as correct for completeness? Thanks